# Subsetting lines as interquarile values in tableau

Tags: subset, tableau-api, quartile

I have been looking around for a while and have not been able to find answers to the following issue that relate to subsetting.

I currently have many lines on a line graph and would only like 4 lines which demonstrate:

1. the lower quartile
2. the median
3. upper quartile
4. one additional line of the category that I choose

The amounts need to be dynamic and change according to other filters that I put on the graph

Answer (score 1):

Box Whisker Plot gives Median,Upper Quartile and Lower Quartile values

You can also drag drag reference lines and bands into the view from the analysis tab